# SwiftUI: Changing an SF Symbol's symbolRenderingMode during an animation causes EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16, sf-symbols

I'm targeting iOS 16 for a project and found that changing an SF Symbol `Image`'s `.symbolRenderingMode` with an `.animation` applied sometimes causes a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` crash with no meaningful stack trace or debug output. Removing `.animation` or keeping the `.symbolRenderingMode` constant prevents crashes. The exception points to the `@main` decorator of the main app file and this is the only stack trace provided:

[image: stack trace showing the app's main entry point]

And this is the tail of the assembly code pointed by the topmost symbol in the stack trace:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong here or is this an SDK bug? I'd like to have the ability to transition between modes, but I'd be okay settling for only `.multicolor` if I have to - just can't figure out why this is happening in the first place. Below is my minimum reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var mode = 0
    var modeName: String {
        mode == 0 ? "Palette" : mode == 1 ? "Multicolor" : "Monochrome"
    }
    var nextModeName: String {
        mode == 0 ? "Multicolor" : mode == 1 ? "Monochrome" : "Palette"
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet.clipboard")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .symbolRenderingMode(mode == 0 ? .palette : mode == 1 ? .multicolor : .monochrome)
                .foregroundStyle(.primary, .secondary)
                .padding()
        
            Text("Current SRM: \(modeName)")
            Button("Tap to set SRM to: \(nextModeName)", action: {mode = mode == 2 ? 0 : mode + 1})
        }
        // Commenting out this line stops crashes
        .animation(.linear, value: mode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug...

I recreated the project using an enum and I was getting the same crash.

After changing the position of `monochrome` a couple of times I could not reproduce it.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct RenderSampleView: View {
    @State var mode: RenderSamples = .palette
    
    var next: RenderSamples{
        RenderSamples(rawValue: mode == RenderSamples.allCases.last ? 0 : mode.rawValue + 1)!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet.clipboard")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .symbolRenderingMode(mode.mode)
                .foregroundStyle(.primary, .secondary)
                .padding()
            
            Text("Current SRM: \(mode.name)")
            Button("Tap to set SRM to: \(next.name)", action: {
                mode = next
            })
        }
        // Commenting out this line stops crashes
        .animation(.linear, value: mode)
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
enum RenderSamples: Int, CaseIterable{
    case palette
    case monochrome // Alternate
    case multicolor
    //case monochrome //Alternate
    var name: String{
        switch self{
        case .palette:
            return "Palette"
        case .multicolor:
            return "Multicolor"
        case .monochrome:
            return "Monochrome"
        }
    }
    var mode: SymbolRenderingMode{
        switch self{
        case .palette:
            return .palette
        case .multicolor:
            return .multicolor
        case .monochrome:
            return .monochrome
        }
    }
    
}



@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct RenderSampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RenderSampleView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - more specifically, it seems to happen anytime you transition away from .multicolor. I will get started on a bug report

Comment: @GregWhatley really weird, I changed simulator devices and it started crashing again but if I click really fast it doesn't crash.

Comment: I seeing the same thing, didn't notice that before

Comment: I have filed feedback FB11595764